# javascript condition always running incorrect if statement

Tags: javascript

I have some JS and my issue is that it now just returns a time out. Please see my code below

I am not sure where I went wrong with this?

```js
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    // With timezone:
    // In Functions/Configure, add NPM name: moment-timezone, version: 0.5.14
    // Timezone function reference: https://momentjs.com/timezone/
    let moment = require('moment-timezone');
    //
    // timezone needed for Daylight Saving Time adjustment
    let timezone = event.timezone || 'America/New_York';
    console.log("+ timezone: " + timezone);
    //
const schedule = new Map([
  [ 0, {open: [00,00], close: [00,00]} ],
  [ 1, {open: [08,30], close: [17,00]} ],
  [ 2, {open: [08,30], close: [17,00]} ],
  [ 3, {open: [08,30], close: [17,00]} ],
  [ 4, {open: [08,30], close: [17,00]} ],
  [ 5, {open: [08,30], close: [17,00]} ],
  [ 6, {open: [00,00], close: [00,00]} ],
])

function isOpen(weekday, hour, minute) {
  const {open, close} = schedule.get(weekday)
  // opening hour
  if (hour == open[0])
    return minute >= open[1]
  // closing hour
  if (hour == close[0])
    return minute < close[1]
  // any minute of any open hour
  return hour > open[0] && hour < close[0]
}
};
```

Comment: Have you verified that `hour`, `minutes` and `dayOfWeek` are what you expect?

Comment: Yes I see on the page it shows a response of closed : 14 3

Comment: What if you tried 2:31?

Answer (score 2):

`.format` returns a String and you are comparing the results to Numbers. Relying on type coercion can be the source of many hard-to-find bugs. I would suggest use of `.hour()`, `.minute()`, etc, which returns a Number. Read [Get/Set Docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/) for more info.

Another thing I would recommend is reference a *single* moment -

```js
const m = moment().tz(timezone)
const hour = m.hour()
const minute = m.minute()
// ...
```

Repeated calls to `moment().tz(...)` is a code smell and can actually cause bugs if your time code depends on millisecond values.

You also (probably) have a bug with your condition -

```js
hour >= 08 && minutes > 30 && hour < 17
```

| hour | minute | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 29 | closed |
| 8 | 30 | closed |
| 8 | 31 | open |
| 8 | 59 | open |
| 9 | 00 | closed |
| 9 | 20 | closed |
| 9 | 30 | closed |
| 9 | 31 | open |
| ... | 20 | closed |
| ... | 30 | closed |
| ... | 31 | open |
| ... | 59 | open |
| ... | 00 | closed |

You may also consider a `schedule` and an `isOpen` function. The function takes the current `weekday`, and the current `hour` and `minute`. This approach also allows you to have different hours on different days, without making the `isOpen` function more complicated -

```js
const schedule = new Map([
  [ 0, {open: [00,00], close: [00,00]} ],
  [ 1, {open: [08,30], close: [17,00]} ],
  [ 2, {open: [08,30], close: [17,00]} ],
  [ 3, {open: [08,30], close: [17,00]} ],
  [ 4, {open: [08,30], close: [17,00]} ],
  [ 5, {open: [08,30], close: [17,00]} ],
  [ 6, {open: [00,00], close: [00,00]} ],
])

function isOpen(weekday, hour, minute) {
  const {open, close} = schedule.get(weekday)
  // opening hour
  if (hour == open[0])
    return minute >= open[1]
  // closing hour
  if (hour == close[0])
    return minute < close[1]
  // any minute of any open hour
  return hour > open[0] && hour < close[0]
}

console.log("Sun @ 08:30", isOpen(0, 08, 30))
console.log("Mon @ 08:00", isOpen(1, 08, 00))
console.log("Mon @ 08:30", isOpen(1, 08, 30))
console.log("Mon @ 09:00", isOpen(1, 09, 00))
console.log("Mon @ 16:59", isOpen(1, 16, 59))
console.log("Mon @ 17:00", isOpen(1, 17, 00))
console.log("Tue @ 12:00", isOpen(2, 12, 00))
console.log("Wed @ 04:00", isOpen(3, 04, 00))
console.log("Thu @ 14:00", isOpen(4, 14, 00))
console.log("Fri @ 15:45", isOpen(5, 15, 45))
console.log("Sat @ 12:00", isOpen(6, 12, 00))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```
Sun @ 08:30 false
Mon @ 08:00 false
Mon @ 08:30 true
Mon @ 09:00 true
Mon @ 16:59 true
Mon @ 17:00 false
Tue @ 12:00 true
Wed @ 04:00 false
Thu @ 14:00 true
Fri @ 15:45 true
Sat @ 12:00 false
```

Comment: That may be *a* problem, but it isn't the *only* problem.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7ca4moqk/ Numbers with comparison operators seems to work

Comment: How many more incorrect results would it take to drop the "probably"?

Comment: @Samathingamajig relying on type coercion is fragile and perfect hiding spot for hard-to-find bugs. Sure `2 > "10"` and `"2" > 10` but what about `"2" > "10"` ? I updated my answer to be a little more clear on this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you check for the minutes to be always greater than 30.
Thus 9:40 is open but 9:20 is closed

Try this

```
if (( ((hour>=8 && minutes>=30)|| (hour >= 9)) && hour < 17) && (dayOfWeek >= 1 && dayOfWeek <= 5)) {
    // "open" from 8:30am to 5pm, EST.
    response = "open";
} else {
    response = "closed";
}
theResponse = response + " : " + hour + " " + dayOfWeek;
console.log("+ Time request: " + theResponse);
```

Comment: I tried your code however now my page just gives me a error saying time out. see updated code in my OP

Comment: I tried your code and it didn't give me any error